# JavaFx Radio Button How to switch between 2 radio buttons as shown in image. I am new to javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

[image: **enter image description here**]
how to change this by switching between these radio buttons.
when i will select rb1 then rb1 values to be shown and same for rb2
Please Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you use a `TabPane` instead of radio buttons? It'll probably be easier to implement.

Comment: to be shown where ? try changing the value inside the `selectedProperty` !

Answer (score 1):

From [This Java2s Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/RadioButtonselectedTogglePropertyListener.htm):

```
final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();    
RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("Rb1");
rb1.setToggleGroup(group);

RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("Rb2");
rb2.setToggleGroup(group);

group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov,
      Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
    if (group.getSelectedToggle() == rb1) {
        nameLabel.setText("M Name");
        // The rest of your logic
    }
    else if(group.getSelectedToggle() == rb2) {
        nameLabel.setText("F Name");
    }
  }
});
```